# Вывод текущей даты в названии страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно выводить текущую дату в заголовке, есть ли стандартный способ/плагин сделать это ? 
Так можна обновить в посте

```
    $main_page_title = array(
    'ID'        => 267, // ID страницы
    'post_title'    => "Сегодня  ".date("d.m.y")." "
);
wp_insert_post( $main_page_title );
```

А как сделать для страницы ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте параметр `post_type` в передаваемый массив

```
$main_page_title = array(
    'ID' => 267, // ID страницы
    'post_title' => "Сегодня  ".date("d.m.y")." ",
    'post_type' => 'page' // тип - страница (по умолчанию post)
);
```